# Push unique key and value into array in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to push key + value into the array with their unique values.

Trying like this:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(check)) {
          console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
          this.inputFields.push({
              //`${key}' : '${value}`
          })
        }
```

Console.log output give me the correct values:

```
Username: ''
Password: ''
```

What i want to do is to push into inputFields the key and value so input fields will be:

Username:
Password:

Without the need of hardcode it into it, because every object in my array have different key and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple : `this.inputFields[key] = value;` should work fine.

Comment: `this.inputFields` is an array and you're using it an object, I gonna update with right example

Answer (score 2):

You could use `[]` to wrap the computed key :

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(check)) {
          console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
          this.inputFields.push({
              [key]:value
          })
        }
```